# Keep bash input on top line of screen

Tags: terminal, tty, console, stty, virtual-consoles

I'd like to keep the `bash` command prompt input at the top of the screen so that outputs from older commands are pushed downwards rather than up.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So, if you `cat` a file, it would be reversed order?

Comment: Nope, but I'd want the chunks of output to be pushed downwards

Comment: `bash` can't do this, because `bash` doesn't even know about screen positions: it just writes to an output file. You would need a terminal emulator that knows about `bash`'s interactive prompt in order know when to reset the cursor and when to scroll the window.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, I'm revisiting this problem and your comment made me look outside of bash and start looking at the whole display stack. I want to remain within the text-based virtual consoles (i.e. no X Windows) so I'd be avoiding terminal emulators for now, but for my GUI sessions I'll certainly look into that. In case anyone comes across this question, my guess is it's to do with tty and I'm currently looking here for inspiration... https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/

Answer (score 8):

Add these lines to your `.bashrc`:

```
prompt_on_top() {
  tput cup 0 0
  tput el
  tput el1
}

pre_cmd() {
  if [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] || [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ]; then
    return
  fi
  printf "\33[2J"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="prompt_on_top"
trap 'pre_cmd' DEBUG
```

`bash` have [PROMPT_COMMAND](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND), which hold the command will be executed before `bash` show prompt. Here we set it to function `prompt_on_top`, which use [tput](http://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_chapter/tput_1.html) to set the cursor at the top of screen.

`bash` also have a way to execute a command before executing any command, using [trap](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-trap) to handle signal `DEBUG`. Here we set it to function `pre_cmd`, which will clear old screen, and do nothing if we did completion ([COMP_LINE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-COMP_005fLINE) is not empty) or run command in `BASH_PROMPT`.

---

There's a limitation with this approach, if command output is too long too fit in a screen, then the output will be override by `prompt_on_top` action. In this case, you need to pipe the output to a pager to read the whole output.

Comment: Thanks for your well explained answer, there's a lot for me to read up on and learn. I've tested your script, and currently it effectively wipes the old output from the screen between commands. I'd like to keep the previous outputs on the screen, below the prompt, and have it so that new outputs are inserted between the prompt and the old output, therefore pushing the old output down the screen.

Comment: For those coming here via a web search, this code https://github.com/swirepe/alwaysontop also "keeps your bash prompt at the top of the screen", plus a couple of other functions.  Does not answer the original question though: older command outputs are deleted as with cuonglm's code.

Comment: An other drawback of this solution, is that you don't have feedback on what command was last executed. That is, `cat file` will show `file` content, but you don't get an immediate feedback of the exact command executed. Ideally the prompt would be followed with an non-expanded + expanded version of the executed command, followed with the std ouput.