# Execute each command in terminal from top line / Execute clear before each command

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

I would like to ask if it is possible to set up in bash so that each command is executed from of the top of terminal window. In other words if it is possible to execute `clear` before each command.

Also I wonder if it is possible to do this without using `preexec()` hook since I have history disabled anyway in bash.

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want to do this? Any command with any kind of output would be moot, e.g. `ls`.

Comment: Put `^[[2J^[[;H` at the beginning of `PS1`, and bask in the inability to see the output of any of your commands.  (Note:  `^[` indicates a literal Escape)

Comment: or just do PS1=\`clear\` ; very effective

Comment: A cat with many skins, POSIX be.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but related and more useful: [Keep bash input on top line of screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218323/keep-bash-input-on-top-line-of-screen)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on your bashrc:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="clear; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

According to the Bash manual:

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>
> > If set, the value is interpreted as a command to execute before the printing of each primary prompt ($PS1).

So every time you press Enter to commit a command, Bash will clear the screen for you after executing the command. You won't be able to see the output of your commands though.

Comment: No, OP wants to clear before command to be executed so output and the command itself must be there, not after commands got executed immediately clear the screen!

Comment: Hmm, yeah I got it all wrong. The event to clear the screen would be, "as soon as I start typing, the screen is cleared", or something like that?

Comment: see this Q&A https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44713/72456

Comment: OP doesn't want to use the preexec. preexec would be my primary answer.

Comment: S/he can refer to another two answers :  )